# How to get url for sibling modules in app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2, microservices

I have an App Engine application that has multiple independent modules.

When [deployed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/designing-microservice-api), these modules become available at `http://<module>.<app_id>.appspot.com`, and when testing locally with `dev_appserver.py mod1.yaml mod2.yaml --port-9000`, then `mod1` runs in `http://localhost:9000` and `mod2` runs in `http://localhost:9001`. All the modules are running on the same project. So far so good.

Let's assume `mod1` needs to talk to `mod2`. Is there a way I can get a url for `mod2` within `mod1`, dynamically?

```
# In mod1's code
import google.some.magic
url_for_mod2 = magic.get_url_for_module('mod2') # http://localhost:9001 or http://mod2.id.appspot.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to build cross-module urls that work on both GAE and on the development server using the `modules.get_hostname()` API. You can find an example in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31145647/4495081

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know it is not possible. As you have 2 services, and maybe more in the future, it seems you are using a distributed microservices architecture and therefore you need to register your services for them to know where the other service is. For that I recommend [etcd](https://github.com/coreos/etcd) it is really pretty easy to use.
A nice fellow also written a [python-client](https://github.com/jplana/python-etcd) for it!